# sqlalchemy schema: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, database-schema, alembic

I'm trying to create 2 tables using SQLAlchemy models that are identical in structure but distinct in purpose, the `Whitelist` and `Blacklist` which also reference a `Magazine` (not shown). They both fkey to an instance of a Campaign (say a political campaign) which in turn has an fkey to a `Politician` model (also not shown).

I'm picturing the `Whitelist`/`Blacklist` to be many:1 to the `Campaign` since there could be multiple white/blacklists for, but when running the migration I get `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "campaigns"`. There also needs to be a M:1 from `Campaign` to `Politician`.

Can someone please explain why this is causing a unique constraint error since the whitelist and blacklist are on separate tables? Also, how would I be able to make this relational schema work?

```
class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = "campaigns"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    politician_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('politician.id'), nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=True)


class Whitelist(Base):
    __tablename__ = "whitelist"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    campaign_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('campaign.id'), nullable=False)
    magazine_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('magazine.id'), nullable=False)


class Blacklist(Base):
    __tablename__ = "blacklist"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    campaign_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('campaign.id'), nullable=False)
    magazine_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('magazine.id'), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the relationship is indeed illegal because of the M:1 from the `Whitelist`/`Blacklist` to `Campaign`, while `Campaign` itself is a M:1 to `Politician`. I instead scrapped that approach and the models now look like:

```
class Campaign(Base):
    __tablename__ = "campaigns"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    politician_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('politician.id'), nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=True)


class Listing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "listings"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    campaign_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('campaign.id'), nullable=False)
    magazine_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('magazine.id'), nullable=False)
    listing_type = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

The original approach was intended to fit a little nicer into `Flask-Admin` but this way is more performant since it will reduce the additional query and join necessary in the previous incarnation. For those that may be thinking of this type of approach to use with `Flask-Admin`, you could use the `inline_model()` to make the UI a little cleaner and easier to manage.

Comment: I can't see why table A --> table B (M:1), table B --> table C (M:1) are illegal.